# Line Breaks not working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, telerik, line-breaks

I have a contact request form which uses telerik:RadTextBoxes.

The whole of the form looks good and everything's where it's meant to be in every browser, apart from Chrome, where one of the input boxes is not picking up on the line breaks!

Is there a way I could maybe do a separate style sheet for Chrome, or a trick to get it to change just in Chrome?

If I take the -20 margin off, it works in Chrome but all the other browsers are messed up!

```
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        <br />
        <br />
        <telerik:RadTextBox runat="server" ID="txtContactNo" Style="margin: -20px 0 0 0">
        </telerik:RadTextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
```

I have now managed to get my spaces the same in every browser by changing the code to this...
`</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
 <telerik:RadTextBox runat="server" ID="txtContactNo" Style="margin:20px 0 0 -10px">
 </telerik:RadTextBox>`

...But now the space in between the input name and the input box is different only in chrome, it comes too close to the input name by 10px, This is because of the `Style="margin:20px 0 0 -10px"` but I cant get rid of this because it is too far away in every other browser, I have already tries playing around with margins and widths but nothing seems to be working in all browsers together!

If anyone could think of anything I could do to fix this help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: you shouldn't be using line breaks for page layout anyways. I'd strip them out and use CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been working on it this morning, and someone mentioned about changing it all to work with tables instead of divs... I did this and cleared all of my code, and now it works!

I'm not sure why the way I was doing it didn't work in Chrome, but it could be that there was just some part of code interfering with it, but tables seems to have done it!

I also found that one of the reason this may have been happening is because of the Required Field Validator, and Regular Expression Validator, they seem to have been pushing the div down further than it needed to be, causing the whole page to break!

So I made sure I made the widths and heights of each table big enough to fit everything.

Thanks for all of your suggestions!! :)

Answer (score 0):

What about `display:block;`? Maybe a screen shot would be helpful...

Comment: I cant do a screen shot because I'm a new user, and the problem still remains when I do display:block, because it works in chrome but is then broken in every other browser...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a top margin of -20px set on the `telerik:RadTextBox` element, which will appear to  cancel out the effect of the `<br />` tag

Comment: I have tried taking the margin off and changing it round but whenever I get it working in Chrome, it breaks in every other browser...

Comment: could you post the code that works in chrome? That would help us to see what exactly the problem is with chrome. When the problem is isolated, you can file a bug at crbug.com.